# Should I be using Facebook user IDs inside my app?

Tags: facebook

I'm currently building a new website which will use Facebook login for authentication.

Should I be using the user's Facebook ID as the user id in my app?

Or should I give my users new user ids?

---

I'm thinking about creating a MySQL table "users" which will have an entry containing the Facebook id for each user (as a primary key), which will be used as a foreign key on the rest of the database.

Is this recommeneded? Am I missing anything?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended for what?
I recommend you not to do it, at least because in future you could want to have authentication via another site (e.g. google, twitter and so on).

Comment: So you recommend that I should have like a dictionary from "facebook id" to "my app user id", and use my app's user id in the rest of my application?